# Emberjs component action not triggering, when switching from display none to display block

Tags: css, ember.js

I have a simple Emberjs component, It consist of a single input field and a collection of `divs` iterating over `items`.

Initially, the `items` div is `display: none` when the input field is focused, the `items` div gets `display: block`.

Each item in the collection has an `action` handler that hits `selectItem`.  With this CSS, clicking the item doesn't hit the action.

However, if the css rule: `.items{ display: none; }` is taken out (line 18 in CSS on the JS fiddle) then click gets through to the action.

Here's a JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dylanjha/NQKvy/959/

A simple component:

```
App.DropDownComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    selectedName: null,
    items: [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}],
    actions: {
        selectItem: function(item){
            alert('Selected ' + item.name);
            this.set('selectedName', item.name);
        }
    }
});
```

And the component's template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/drop-down">
  <h1>Drop Down</h1>
  <div>
   {{ input value=selectedName id="form-input" }}
    <div class='items'>
      {{#each item in items}}
        <div class='item' {{action 'selectItem' item}}>
           {{ item.name }}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Some simple CSS styling the input and the items div

```
#form-input{
    width:200px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px;
}
#form-input:focus + .items{
    opacity:1;
    display:block;
}
.items{
    font-size:20px;
    -webkit-transition:opacity .2s ease;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you lose focus from your input box you are hiding the drop down.  So even though it may look like you are clicking on the element, really you are clicking on nothing.

That being said, you'll need to keep the div in view until the action has been clicked (or whatever other reasons).

For that I'd probably use Ember.TextField and hook up to the `focusIn` event triggering the options, then close when it's been selected.

#### Custom TextField

```
App.TextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  focusOut: function(evt) {
    this.sendAction('focus-out');
  },
  focusIn: function(){
    this.sendAction('focus-in');   
  }
});
```

#### Template

```
{{view App.TextField value=selectedName id='form-input' focus-in='open'}}
<div {{bind-attr class=':items visible:showItems:hideItems'}}>
  {{#each item in items}}
    <div class='item' {{action 'selectItem' item}}>
       {{ item.name }}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

#### Modified component

```
App.DropDownComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    selectedName: null,
    visible: false,
    items: [{id: 1, name: 'one'}, {id: 2, name: 'two'}],
    actions: {
        selectItem: function(item){
            alert('Selected ' + item.name);
            this.set('selectedName', item.name);
            this.set('visible', false);
        },
        open: function(){
            this.set('visible', true);
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7e9c/

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  This works, but doesn't fully solve my problem.  With your implementation, if the user clicks away, outside list, I want the list to close.

I tried this by adding `focus-out='close'` and a `close` action that `this.set('visible', false);`, but again... I have the same problem.  Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/dylanjha/Pf26q/1/